# Simple Ember Data Issue with Mirage (Error: Encountered a resource object with an undefined type )

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I have some experience with Ember.js, and am now going through creating a new project, with [Mirage](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/) to stub the data for now.

I'm going through the [Ember.js Tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/installing-addons/) step by step but keep getting this error when querying for records:

`Encountered a resource object with an undefined type (resolved resource using DS.JSONAPISerializer)`

I do realize that a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088525/emberjs-2-connect-to-an-api-flask-encountered-a-resource-object-with-an-undefi) has been asked, but it did not include the Mirage addon, and I also went through all of the techniques answered in that question.

---

`mirage/config.js`

```
export default function() {
  this.namespace = '/api'

  this.get('/todos', function() {
    return {
      data: [
        {
          text: 'Bring in garbage cans',
          completed: false,
          timesViewed: 3
        },
        {
          text: 'Look at the plants',
          completed: false,
          timesViewed: 0
        }
      ]
    }
  })
}
```

---

`app/models/todo.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr(),
    completed: DS.attr(),
    timesViewed: DS.attr()
});
```

---

`app/routes/index.js`

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.findAll('todo')
    }
});
```

---

`app/adapters/application.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});
```

---

I've been formatting the response from Mirage in all kinds of ways, even doing the double quotes on keys, but that shouldn't be necessary since I believe mirage serializes it.

Any help on what I'm missing here is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you are facing is due to the fact that your mirage data isn't formatted as-per JSON-API specifications.

`mirage/config.js` =>

```
export default function() {
this.namespace = '/api'

this.get('/todos', function() {
  return {
    data: [
      {
          type: "todos",
          id: 1,
          attributes: {
          text: "Bring in garbage cans",
          completed: false,
          timesViewed: 3
          }
      },
      {
          type: "todos",
          id: 2,
          attributes: {
          text: "Look at the plants",
          completed: false,
          timesViewed: 0
          }
      }
      ]
  }
});
```

}

Try out this code and see if the issue is resolved.

If you are looking for a way to dynamically generate mirage data according to JSON-API spec., see this sample code -> [sample code for dynamic mirage data](https://github.com/siwalikm/flight-booking-poc-in-ember/blob/master/mirage/config.js)! Cheers

Comment: I don't see why your sample code for dynamic mirage data should be needed. Mirage supports factories, allows to seed database using scenarios and has shorthands for simple routes like that.

Comment: @jelhan You're correct, factories support that, this is just an hand-rolled implementation if you're looking for something quick.

Comment: I would argue that using mirage's default for this is much quicker and less code.